# Thrice nested "OS" in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x, authentication

This Python main is what greets the user to a thrice nested super duper barebones OS.  The entire rest of my code isn't bug free but this section is, and it feels dirty anyway.  I'd like to know how to make it better, by adhering to conventions, or by removal of fatty code.

*NOTE: I am not looking to use classes with any of this, because part of the challenge of this program is structuring it with procedural means.*

```
from functions import *

innerLoopFlag = False
while True:
 if innerLoopFlag:
     break
 makeNew = raw_input("Login || Create New Account... ")
 if makeNew == "c-na":
     ui = createAccount()
     createFileSyst(ui)
     break
 if makeNew == "l-a":
     ui = [raw_input("Username... ").strip(),pw("Password... ").strip()]
     if not os.path.isdir(ui[0]):
         print "It appears that this username doesn't exist, please log in legitimately or create an account"
         continue
     if ui:
         while True:
             if takeCheck(ui):
                 print "Successful login..."
                 innerLoopFlag = True
                 break
             else:
                 print "Failure logging in, retrying..."

all()
print "Goodbye", ui[0]
```

Comment: The Python convention for variable names is `lowercase_with_underscores`. You can find the Python style guide in [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 10):

I don't understand what you mean by "thrice nested", or why you call this an OS. I'm reviewing it as a login prompt.

> The entire rest of my code isn't bug free but this section is

Beware of believing something is bug-free. It never is. This is especially important for code which needs to be secure, as this presumably does.

Now for the review:

Many variables need names that say what they mean:

- What does `innerLoopFlag` mean? Something like `successful_login`, right?
- `makeNew`: `command`?
- `ui`: `credentials`?
- `createFileSyst`: (There's no need to abbreviate such a rarely used name.) Something like `createUserDirectory`? But it should be called from `createAccount`, not here.
- `takeCheck`: What does this do? Is it `isValidLogin`?
- `all`: Is it something like `runUserSession`?

Simplifications:

- The conditional break at beginning of the loop can become the loop condition: `while not innerLoopFlag`.
- The `if ui` test is always true.
- The inner loop can be simplified by making the loop condition do the work:

  ```
  while not takeCheck(ui):
      print "Failure logging in, retrying..."
  print "Successful login..."
  break
  ```

  This also makes `innerLoopFlag` unnecessary. However, why are you retrying at all? Do you expect login to fail and then succeed?

Bugs:

- Stripping the password is not safe, because passwords can contain whitespace.
- **Security hole**: the `isdir` call lets anyone test for the existence of arbitrary directories. Imagine trying to log in with a username like '../../../some/private/directory'. Also, it depends on the current directory. Is there a user table you could look the user up in instead?
- (Revealing whether a user exists is also sometimes considered a security hole, but that's debatable.)

Usability:

- Are "c-na" and "l-a" user-supplied strings, or generated by `raw_input`, or what?
- Output ending in "... " looks like a progress message ("Please wait..."), not a prompt. "Login: " and "Password: " are the standard prompts.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It's a lovely answer you have here. We need more people like you.

Answer (score 3):

So why not use functions for the steps?

```
work_to_be_done = True

while work_to_be_done:
    if makeNew == "c-na":
        do_make_account()
        work_to_be_done = False
    elif makeNew == "l-a":
        result = login()
        if result:
            work_to_be_done = False
```